What was the name of this movie with opening scene where man snaps woman 's neck as they are having sex?
Warning: this is a graphic movie.  Read at your own risk. There was a movie from a few years ago that had a very memorable opening scene that was intense and described below.  Please help to identify.
Movie Color: It was in color
Type of Movie: Live action
Language: English
Approximate Release Date: Either 80s, 90s or 2000s
Country: Most likely American
Where This Was Seen: On Showtime or HBO cable channels late night
The opening scene had a naked man and woman having sex where the woman is sitting on the man facing him. The woman is a brunette or dark hair.  Both were caucasian. After nearing climax, the man puts his arms around the woman's head and snaps her neck. Her limp body falls on him.  
Not sure if the following plot detail is a mix up with another movie but he goes around killing prostitutes. One prostitute is a black woman he drags head first into his vehicle and drives off with her legs dangling. Another scene implies the killer has murdered a prostitute and cannibalized her vagina.

Possible duplicate : https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75620/name-of-this-slasher-movie-released-few-years-ago
